# Formulating a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A particle is moving with unit speed. Its angular speed is given by this equation:

$$ \frac{d\phi}{ds}=\frac{3\sin^2(\phi - \alpha)-2}{r\sin(\phi - \alpha)} $$

where $\phi$ is the angle representing the particle's direction of movement , $\alpha$ and $r$ are the standard angle and distance from the origin of the particle's position in polar coordinates.

I don't know how to, at least, express the differential equation of the path the particle takes, so if someone can help, or, if it's not even possible to formulate it, to give some hints to why it is impossible... Here, $ds$ is the arc length satisfying

$$ ds=\sqrt{dr^2+r^2 \, d\alpha^2} $$

which basically says that the particle is moving with unit speed.
I accept the differential equation/s written in any kind of coordinate system.

Comment: Wow, it seems it's a tough one :)

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74375/2451

Answer (score 3):

You can use the definition of $ds$ to get the following equation

$$\frac{ds}{r d\phi} = \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{r^2}\left ( \frac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^2} = \frac{\sin{\phi}}{3 \sin^2{\phi}-2}$$

(I am ignoring the $\alpha$ as an unimportant phase constant.)  Rearranging this produces the following equation:

$$\frac{dr}{r} = d\phi \sqrt{\frac{\sin^2{\phi}}{(3 \sin^2{\phi}-2)^2}-1}$$

So, all we need to do is integrate both sides to get $r=r(\phi)$.  Unfortunately, the integral is extremely difficult and is a jumble of incomplete elliptic integrals, etc.  But there you have it.

Comment: $\alpha$ is the angle defining the position of the particle in polar coordinates, which means it is not a constant, and it also depends on s, the arc lenght.

Comment: @BinaryBurst: so then you're really up s**t's creek.

Comment: Though, is it correct to ignore the $\alpha$ in the last integral, like if I substitute the $\phi$ with $\phi-\alpha$ would I get the correct answer?

Comment: If $\alpha$ can be even approximated as a constant, then what I did is OK, good even.  However, if $\alpha=\alpha(s)$, then the equation becomes a miasma, impossible to simplify.